# Thousands of 4776 events

Tags: printing, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm facing a problem which causing thousands of successful 4776 events on DCs. I figured out that some kind of network printer enumeration causing it. Every refreshing or opening printers in word for example, triggers a lot of 4776. It takes place even when user doesn't use computer so it is locked. Any idea why it works like that? I suspect that it is caused by opening printer named pipe, I see in ProcMon create, close file on pipe\spools printer path. Server is W2K8 R2 , client W10

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This problem ***"Thousands of 4776 events"*** usually occurs every time that a credential validation occurs using *NTLM authentication.* It shows successful and unsuccessful credential validation attempts.

> Only for the authoritative accounts this error occurs. For domain
> accounts, the domain controller is authoritative. For local accounts,
> the local computer is authoritative. This event also generates when a  workstation unlock event occurs.

**Obtain the source workstation address from 4776 event log and please check below steps:**

- Try checking whether the user is entering *wrong credentials* to run scheduled tasks, start services etc.
- Try checking the *credential management* to know if there are any old credentials present in cache.
- While mounting the network disk check whether you have entered *wrong password.*
- Check if there are any *third-party programs* that cache the user's wrong password.

**References**:

[4776(S, F) The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account. (Windows 10) - Windows security | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4776).

[Event ID 4776 / 0xc00006a - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/142898/event-id-4776-0xc00006a.html).